# underline the nth word of a string based on an array in php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, string, replace

I have passed some paginated data to my blade view like this:

```
<div>
     @foreach ($result as $item)
        {{ $item->text}} :
        <br>
     @endforeach
     {{ $result->links() }}
</div>

//outputs 3 strings
```

I have an array with 3 elements that contains the respective locations of each word in each string that should be "underlined":

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 19
  1 => 5
  2 => 3
]
```

So 19 means, the 19th word of the first string that will be underlined. Likewise 5 and 3 mean the 5th and the 3rd words in the second and the third string.

So, what should I write in my loop to underline nth word in a string based on a given array?

Can you please give me a tip?

Comment: have you tried explode? should be fairly straightforward after that, using the value from the underline array, use that as key on the exploded string containing the words via the foreach key and apply the underline, (underline tag or via css whichever you prefer)

Comment: Yes, and the answer reflected that.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought on this would be to break out the string into an array, change the item in the array and then implode the array back into a string.

```
$wordArray = ['3','4','7'];

// explodes the string into words assuming the space
$stringArray = explode(' ','This is a simple testing string');

// get the word from array to change 
// in this case 0 would be the 3rd word
// index would be the - 1 as arrays start at 0, word  number starts at 1 
$stringIndex = $wordArray[0] - 1; 

$stringArray[$stringIndex] = '<u>' . $stringArray[$stringIndex] . '</u>'; 

// then implode the array again.
$alteredString = implode(' ',$stringArray);
```

which should result in

`This is <u>a</u> simple testing string`

This can be done outside of the blade template leaving blade to just do basic output if needed. Ofcourse this could be pushed into a more useful function but it will hopefully help.

Comment: [Test the code](https://3v4l.org/DaNLM) before posting an answer. PHP arrays are zero-based, so `3` isn't the third word in the exploded array, but the fourth.

Comment: @El_Vanja My apologies for that, great spot. I have updated the code to reflect that (and tested) - https://3v4l.org/OFfIK

Comment: @michaelpengelly Thank you very much. The "explode, change, implode" helped me a lot. Though, I had thought that there could be a specific function for that kind of tweaking.